# How to update specific node in Firebase?

Tags: firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database, nosql

How do I update eImageUrl on an existing employee? The node I'm trying to access looks like this:

```
Employees
  KTpWLCrQTTSfQnTCn5w
    eId : "1000"
    deptId : "10"
    eImageUrl ""
  KTqWLCrVVTMfQsTCw6n
    eId : "1001"
    deptId : "10"
    eImageUrl ""
```

Values such as `KTpWLCrQTTSfQnTCn5w` for each employee were auto generated using `childByAutoId()`.

I have the `eId` for the employee I want to update. I've tried the following:

```
databaseRef.child("Employees").child("10001").setValue(["eImageUrl": eImageUrl])
```

but that creates another node under Employees:

```
Employees
  KTpAQCrYIBSfQxTCn2w
    eImageUrl "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/c0/myapp.com/a/employee.jpg"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firebase's push ids are great for collections of items that don't have a natural key or items that need to be stored chronologically. But when items do have a natural key, you're often better off storing them under that key.

So in this case, I'd consider storing the employees under their employee id.

```
Employees
  "eId_1000"
    deptId : "10"
    eImageUrl ""
  "eId_1001"
    deptId : "10"
    eImageUrl ""
```

I've given the employee ids a alphanumeric prefix, which ensures that the Firebase client won't try to interpret them as an array.

With this structure in place, you can modify the employee record with `updateChildValues()`:

```
databaseRef.child("Employees").child("eId_10001").updateChildValues(["eImageUrl": eImageUrl])
```

Or call `setValue()` one level lower in the tree:

```
databaseRef.child("Employees/eId_10001/eImageUrl").setValue(eImageUrl)
```

**Update**

Since you indicate wanting to stick to your current data structure, this query will work for that:

```
let employees = databaseRef.child("Employees")
let query = employees.queryOrdered(byChild: "eId").queryEqual(toValue: "1000")
query.observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
    snapshot.ref.updateChildValues(["eImageUrl": eImageUrl])
})
```

Comment: I'd rather not do that because then you have to make sure the ID doesn't already exist. A random ID is better but it is better if Firebase creates it.

Comment: I've updated my answer with a query that works on your current data structure. But your code suggest that you already assume that eId is unique. I'd consider moving to a data model that matches with how your think about it in practice.

Comment: Thanks. I'm going to use what you suggested and let the auto generated employee IDs (by Firebase) be the root of each node instead of some auto generated unassociated ID.

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the pushid first to perform a database update

```
databaseRef.child('Employees').orderByChild('eId').equalTo(1001).on('value',function(snapshot){

snapshot.forEach(function(data) {

   databaseRef.child("Employees/"+data.key+"/eImageUrl").set(eImageUrl); 

                                });  });
```

Hope this helped